# In node-sqlite3, how to wait until run() is finished?

Tags: node-sqlite3

With node-sqlite3 and the following code, `INSERT` can happen before `CREATE TABLE` finishes:

```
db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");
const stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
stmt.run("Ipsum");
stmt.finalize();
```

The documentation wraps the code in `db.serialize(() => { ... })`, but in my case this would make the code unwieldly. Is there any way to wait for `db.run` to finish?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `db.serialize` without an argument to serialize all following commands:

```
db.serialize();
db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");
const stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
stmt.run("Ipsum");
stmt.finalize();
```

Comment: There's a good example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#Usage

Comment: @DaveH. I quoted that example in the question and was looking for a way that didn't require putting the entire code in an argument to `db.serialize`, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Yes you did. I see that now. Obviously, it was past my bedtime when I replied.